# PHP - Como configurar o .env de Laravel para acessar diferentes bancos de dados e diferentes idiomas?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel

Eu estou trabalhando num sistema (portal) que oferece serviço para 19 países. Para cada país existe um banco de dados e cada país com o seu dicionário de idioma (mesmo países com mesmo idioma, possuem dicinários diferenets EX: méxico e espanha). O sistema foi construído em PHP, IIS windows 7. Estou querendo migrar o sistema para php - laravel, apache, LInux. O primeiro desafio que estou encontrando é a configuração do aqruivo .ENV do laravel (última versão). Ele aceita um idioma e um banco de dados.

Enntão a lógica é a segunte: quando o usuário escreve br.portal.mycompany.com o sistema deve recuperar as credenciais de acesso ao banco de dados br_portal e tbm recuperar os labels em portugues (br) no banco de dados de dicionário.

Como poderia configurar o env para aceitar diferentes credenciais para diferentes bancos de dados e diferentes idiomas, baseados nas diferentes possibilidades de url ? Ex: br.portal.mycompany.com, us.portal.mycompany.com, es.portal.mycompany.com, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar diferentes conexões.

No arquivo config/databases.php existe a conexão do seu banco default, mas voce pode criar outras conexões. Assim:

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

        'mysql2' => [ // Aqui você define o nome da conexão
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_BR_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_BR_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_BR_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_BR_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_BR_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
```

Depois no arquivo .env você coloca os dados para o acesso. Assim:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql // Banco padrão
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


DB_BR_CONNECTION=mysql // Outros bancos
DB_BR_HOST=localhost
DB_BR_PORT=3306
DB_BR_DATABASE=database
DB_BR_USERNAME=root
DB_BR_PASSWORD=
```

E para fazer uma consulta no banco você precisa definir qual conexão a aplicação deve usar. Assim:

```
$sql = DB::connection('name_connection')->table('name_table')->get();
```